# What are the specs for a 1980 Schwinn Superior Road Bike?

Tags: road-bike, vintage, schwinn

Generally referred to as the Baby Paramount made with Reynolds 531 frame tubing and or Nervar dropouts and some of Campagnolo Gran Sport components and a Brooks saddle…

Answer (score 1):

According to  https://bikehistory.org/bikes/superior/?expand_article=1   there either wasn't a specific 1980 model, or they don't have info on it.

There is info from the 1978 and 1981 catalogues.

|  | 1978 | 1981 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Frame | Schwinn hand built chrome- moly tubing, internally lugged construction. Tubular fork with eyelets and chrome tips. | Reynolds 531 double butted, Tange front fork. |
| Wheels | Aluminum alloy rims. Exclusive large flange Schwinn-Approved quick release hubs. 27" x 1 1/8" Schwinn Super Record high pressure tires. | Super Champion (700 C) on Campagnolo Gran Sport hubs with quick release and Schwinn 250 gram Super 700 tires |
| Handlebar | Alloy road racing. Cloth handlebar tape. | Sakae |
| Stem | Aluminum alloy with recessed bolt | Sakae |
| CrankSet | Cotterless aluminum alloy. 170 mm crankarms. | Campagnolo Gran Sport, 170 mm arms. 42-52 chainwheels. |
| Derailleurs | Schwinn-Approved GT-295 front. Sun Tour V-GT rear. | Campagnolo Gran Sport F&R |
| Gears | 40-54 front. 14-17-21-26-32 freewheel. | Regina (14-24) |
| Brakes | Schwinn-Approved aluminum alloy center pull. | Campagnolo Gran Sport |
| Pedals | Rattrap with toe clips and straps. Reflectorized. | Campagnolo Gran Sport with toe clips and straps |
| Saddle | Nylon base with vinyl cover | Brooks BN5 |
| Weight | ~28 lbs | 24.8 lbs |

There's more info at the linked site.